# Is there a way to parse JSON without names?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, json, loop, gtl

we have a simple JSON structure. This structure has no names like this:

```
["value1","value2"]
```

Is there a way to parse/use this in Marketing Cloud? We don't have to make decisions. Everything in the JSON we will use.

Comment: Yes. This is an array of strings, so parse it into a `List<String>`.

Comment: I am working in the Marketing Cloud. So if I understand you correctly we can do this with javascropt/SSJS in our emails with List<String>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an alternative answer: assuming you want to display this inside an email, it might be better to use AMPscript instead of SSJS to pull and parse the data from your array using the [BuildRowsetFromString](https://ampscript.guide/buildrowsetfromstring/) function:

```
%%[
set @data = AttributeValue("data") /* get data from a sendable DE */

/* build a simple string from array */
set @string = replace(@data, "[", "") 
set @string = replace(@string, "]", "")
set @string = replace(@string, '"', '')

/* build a rowset */
set @rows = BuildRowsetFromString(@string,",")
set @rowCount = rowCount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    set @row = row(@rows, @i) /* get row based on counter */
    set @value = field(@row,1)
    Output(v(@value))
    
  next @i 
endif ]%%
```

Adding additional answer from the comments.
In case you want to have two separate variables for each of the values, you can do this instead of the loop:

```
%%[
set @data = AttributeValue("data") /* get data from a sendable DE */

/* build a simple string from array */
set @string = replace(@data, "[", "") 
set @string = replace(@string, "]", "")
set @string = replace(@string, '"', '')

/* build a rowset */
set @rows = BuildRowsetFromString(@string,",")
set @rowCount = rowCount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

set @row = row(@rows, 1) /* get first value */     
set @value1 = field(@row,1)             
set @row = row(@rows, 2) /* get second value */     
set @value2 = field(@row,1)    
If @value1 == "something" or @value2 == "something" then

]%% <br>some text<br> %%[

endif
endif ]%%
```

You can use and/or in the condition or do two separate conditions using elseif/else depending on your needs. Read more about using conditional statements here: https://ampscript.guide/statements/

Comment: Yes this works. One question about this script. Here you loop over the array. Is it possible to read the data without the loop? So with this example array ["value1","value2"] in mind, suppose I want to use only 1 value eg only value 2? With the above script you will now always see the fallback (else). And if I remove the fallback and use an OR statement, I get to see my value twice.

Comment: If you only want to always use the second value, you can do something like this instead of the loop: `set @row = row(@rows, 2) /* get second row only */
    set @value = field(@row,1)
    Output(v(@value))`

Comment: It's not that I always want to use the second value. Sometimes only value 1, sometimes only value 2 or a combination of the values. So if I use:
if @ value == "value1" then ]%%
    <br>some text for value 1<br>
    %%[ else ]%%
    <br>fallback text for other values<br>
    %%[ endif

It shows value1 but also the fallback.

And if I use:

if @ value == "value1" or @ value == "value2" then ]%%
    <br>some text for value 1<br>


then it shows both values instead of one of them. Hopefully this make sens to you.

Comment: In that case you can do something like this instead of the loop: `set @row = row(@rows, 1) /* get first value */
    set @value1 = field(@row,1)
   
    set @row = row(@rows, 2) /* get second value */
    set @value2 = field(@row,1)
 

If @value1 == "something" or @value2 == "something" then
…
endif`. You can use and/or in the condition or do two separate conditions using elseif/else.

Comment: Ah great. This is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine SSJS and AMPscript, use SSJS to loop and parse the values and then [set value](https://ampscript.guide/setvalue/) into an AMPscript variable to process. For example:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1");

var list = ["value1","value2"];
for (var i =0; i < list.length; i++) {
    Variable.SetValue("@element", list[i]);
</script>

%%[
    /* Put your AMPscript here */
    Output(Concat(@element, '<br>'));
]%%

<script runat="server"> 
}

</script>
```

Output:

```
value1
value2
```

Comment: Great. I will give it a try.

Comment: Your example worked. But how can I target a data extention where the JSON is in a attribute field?

Comment: And can you act on the output? So for exampe, if value1 then show this text, and for value2 another text etc.

Comment: @Martijne You would need to know how to retrieve records from a Data Extension. You can also do with other actions depends on what you are going to do. I recommend you should open a new topic if you have further questions